# Устройство цикла обработки команд в nodejs

Tags: node.js

1) Гарантирует ли nodejs что операции приема(отправки) для одного и того-же сокета будут последовательны(будут выполнены в одном потоке)?

2) Гарантирует ли nodejs что **ВСЕ** операции для одного и того-же сокета будут последовательны(будут выполнены в одном потоке)?

```
var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(666, '127.0.0.1');


var val;

client.on('data', function(data) {
     val="big data recv"; 
//????
});

client.on('error', function(err) {
     val="big data err"; 
//????
});
```

И если они не последовательны, то как себя поведет программа при работе с глобальной переменной в этих функциях

**UPD**
Хорошо, нода дает гарантию на сохранность валидного значения в общей переменной(в принципе, если б не давала, то были б примитивы синхронизации). А вот каким образом достигается эта гарантия, неужели в ноде действительно только 1 рабочий поток(разве это не вызывает проблем с производительностью)? Может там внутри какой-либо умный thread pool?

Создал сервер, промониторил через диспетчер, при новом подключение рождает 4 потока, при частых запросах родил еще 1, *вроде*  thread pool это все-таки и процессор использоваться при таком подходе будет на полную.
Из сего вытекает вопрос: Использование общей переменной приведет к просадке производительности(затраты на синхронизацию)? Стоит ли минимизировать использование общих переменных?

Comment: Под "_синхронны_" вы понимаете "_последовательны_"? Или что-то другое?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, да, именно так и понимаю

Comment: Так как там используется eventloop, то запросы будут поступать именно в той последовательности, в которой они пришли. И да, они будут выполнены в одном потоке, так как нода однопоточна (с точки зрения программиста).

Comment: @KoVadim, а это гарантирует, что завершится обработка запросов именно в том порядке, в котором пришли? Мне казалось, что таки нет.

Comment: @KoVadim, хорошо, а каким образом достигается эта однопоточность (с точки зрения программиста), как я понимаю, внутри потоки там все равно есть, если одновременно в двух выполяемых потоках будет запрошена общая переменная это приведет к просадке производительности(затраты на синхронизацию) или она сделана более хитро?

Comment: @DanielOlivo, "запуск на выполнение" и "завершение" - разные вещи. _Выполнение_ каждой из функций начнется последовательно, а вот насчет окончания работы этих функций такого утверждать нельзя. Сами функции тоже могут быть _асинхронными_.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ну я вот об этом и подумал, таким образом нодовская однопоточная асинхронность вполне может непредсказуемо менять значение глобальной переменной.

Comment: @Kopkan, внутри никаких потоков нет. Весь JS код выполняется **строго** в одном потоке. А вот ввод/вывод (который реализуется во внешних библиотеках) действительно может реализовываться во вспомогательных потоках

Comment: @DanielOlivo, за глобальные переменные давно пора бить по рукам. Тем боле в node.js. А что касается непредсказуемости: то тут все **абсолютно прозрачно**, никакой магии нет

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, то есть в верхнем примере все таки не может быть того, что при двух запросах значение val меняется во втором запросе раньше, чем используется где-то в первом? Я так думаю вопрос то в этом состоял.

Comment: @DanielOlivo, это зависит от времени выполнения функций: в принципе глобальная переменная может принять любое из значений (в зависимости от того, какое из событий произойдет раньше). Однако, содержимое функций **не может** выполняться одновременно (однопоточность, все дела), только друг за другом.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, спасибо. Так я и представлял себе все.

Comment: «Создал сервер» — а конкретнее? Вам тут уже пять раз сказали, что нода сама по себе однопоточна. Это не мешает запустить несколько отдельных процессов которые будут выполнятся параллельно, но при этом у них нет ничего общего, глобальная переменная в одном потоке никак не связана с такой же в другом потоке.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, хорошо, у меня 4 ядерный проц, что б на полную его использовать 4 ноды нужно запустить?

Comment: В первом приближении — да. Для упрощения жизни есть всякие pm2, strongloop process manager и т.п., но в конечном счёте получается несколько запущенных процессов ноды.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript - однопоточный язык, в нем нет и никогда не будет многопоточности.

Если вы уже работали с node.js, то должны заметить, что вместо многопоточности широко используется асинхронность.

Проблемы с производительностью это не вызывает. В других языках однопоточная работы может приводить к проблемам потому что есть куча функций из сторонних библиотек, которые делают что-то синхронно, и легко пропустить какую-то.

Но в node.js с самого начала была принята асинхронная концепция - и синхронных функций практически нет. Те, которые есть, используются только на этапе инициализации (обычно для чтения конфигов и загрузки модулей).

Поэтому однопоточность здесь приводит не к задержкам - а к экономии системных ресурсов и лучшей работе под нагрузкой. Именно благодаря однопоточности node.js находится по способности держать нагрузку в одном ряду с такими серверами как nginx и lighttpd, и значительно обгоняет всякие там Apache и Tomcat.

---

Те потоки, которые вы наблюдали через диспетчер - это служебные нативные потоки, которые нужны для того чтобы делать блокирующие системные вызовы.

Comment: То есть, как я понял, в ноде только 1 главный цикл выполнения, но если задача долгая, то для неё создается поток, после завершения её этот поток добавляет задачу, которую прочитает главный цикл выполнения(получается некий callback), таким способом ничего не блокируется и как-бы работает в 1 потоке. Верно?

Comment: @Kopkan "долгая" - не вполне корректное слово. Правильнее - блокирущий системный вызов.

Comment: нет, не верно,если в не асинхронной программе мы сделаем 1-й строкой вывести надпись в консоль "привет" затем на 2-й строке прочитаем файл, и на 3-й строке напишем "пока",то всё выполниться именно в такой последовательности,если мы напишем это в ноде и сделаем чтение файла асинхронным, то мы увидим сначала строчку привет, потом начнётся открытие файла,и не дожидаясь его окончания мы увидим строчку "пока",то есть если файл большой нам ненадо ждать пока он весь прогрузиться,мы можем делать ещё что-то,а когда он загрузится сработает Калбек-функция которая выведет например строку что файл прочитан

Comment: @vnn198 а теперь объясните, что именно из сказанного вами противоречит тому, что писал я.

Comment: Ничего не противоречит, я просто объяснил это более человеческим образом.